# why variable losing its value within the loop

Tags: bash, shell

i am trying to use the loop variable within the loop. But it seems that it is loosing its value after using one time(may be i am misunderstanding). Here is my code

```
for i in {2000..2014}
do
    echo “training  representation$i_by_$i and testing representation$1999_by_$i”
done
```

I want the output should be like this-

`training  representation2000_by_2000 and testing representation1999_by_2000`

but the  actual output is like this-

```
training representation2000 and testing representation1999_by_??
```

can any body help?

Comment: is your `$1` actually `1`?

Comment: Obviously the value isn't being lost, or you wouldn't have any `2000`s in your output.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using curly quotes around your string. The character `”` is not a special character to the shell, so it's being treated as part of the variable name. But there's no variable named `i”`.

Change to ASCII double quotes around the string. Also, since `_` can be in a variable name, you need to use `${i}` when the variable is followed by that character (or any other character that can be in a variable name); otherwise, it's looking for a variable named `$i_by_`.

Finally, `$1999` is being interpreted as `$1` (the first argument to the script)`followed by`999`. To prevent that, you need to escape the`$`.

```
for i in {2000..2014}
do
    echo "training  representation${i}_by_$i and testing representation\$1999_by_$i"
done
```

And stop using a word processor to edit programs. Use a programming editor, it won't auto-correct your quoting.

Comment: That and `$i_by_` is not the same as `$i`.

Comment: Can a variable name contain special characters? I doubt that.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, it absolutely can contain underscores.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, I was reading you as responding to Benjamin rather than to the first sentence of Barmar's answer, so I actually misread your point.

Comment: @Barmer your ans does not giving me the expected ans by the way i found me expected ans by myself but thanks anyway.
"training  representation${i}_by_${i} and testing representation1999_by_${i}"
And the person gave me a downvote can you please share the reason. I want to learn. Thanks

Comment: Needed to escape the `$` before `$1999`. Try it now.

Comment: Why do you have the `$` before `1999` in the first place? It's not in the desired output. Maybe that was a typo?

Comment: From the `bash` man page, a named parameter (usually called a variable):  "*A  word  consisting  only  of alphanumeric characters and under-scores, and beginning with an alphabetic character or an  under-score.  Also referred to as an identifier.*"  So not a `"`.

Comment: @cdarke You're right, and I can't actually reproduce his problem for that part of the output. So I'm not sure why it doesn't print the last `$i` correctly, unless he didn't copy his script correctly to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're missing some quotes, you can use that kind of quotes, but when you add _ after calling the variable `$i`, bash thinks you're calling another variable called `$i_by_`.

Try:

```
for i in {2000..2014}
do
    echo "training  representation"$i"_by_"$i"and testing representation1999_by_$i"
done
```

With that you're printing 5 objects, `training  representation`, `$i`,`_by_`,`$i` and `and testing representation1999_by_$i`

Getting the output you need:

```
“training representation2000_by_2000and testing representation1999_by_2000”
```

Also, at the end you had `$1999`, i believe by mistake.

EDIT: As suggested at the comments, you can also use:

```
echo "training representation${i}_by_${i}and testing representation1999_by_${i}"
```

To use the variables inside the quote.

@Barmar: Those quotes are fine, the problem is not there; i tried with both and worked the same way.

Comment: Expanding variables unquoted is very bad form. Look at what happens if your code is run with `IFS=1234567890`. Use `${i}` inside quotes to disambiguate string concatenation; don't end quotes before an expansion and thus subject that expansion to string-splitting (as by characters in IFS) and globbing.

Comment: That's another way, i know, but if the iteration variable is well know with regular values, shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: As I said above (and gave an example for demonstration purposes), even if the value expanded contains only known characters, an irregular value for IFS can still cause problems as above.